# Make your deleted questions and answers more discoverable

Tags: feature-request, design, deleted-posts, activity

[As of a recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) one can now see all their deleted posts.

The link to this page is however quite hidden. You first need to go to either your [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions) or [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=answers) page, scroll all the way to the bottom and there you can click the "Deleted questions / answers" button. I know we don't want to emphasise deleted stuff, as the general opinion is that it will lead to more people complaining about their posts being deleted, but as it currently stands I find it very well hidden.

Can we opt to move the link to the top of the page, and place it on either of the red X's in below screenshot?

[image]

We could use a small font behind my "**102 Questions**" to state "x deleted questions" or add a button or link to the right side. A link would most likely be better then a button, as the deleted questions isn't a sort but a page on its own.

Comment: Catija was the main driving force behind this change. Felippe also helped tremendously with adding paging to *Deleted Answers* and upgrading the UI on that page.

Comment: This is intentionally obscure. We explicitly don't want to make it easier to find. The suggestion you have here makes it front-and-center and not hidden at all.

Comment: @Catija that depends on how often these tabs in the activity page are used at all, I suspect they are used very little, hence there is no need to hide them any deeper then this. Some data on how often the questions and answers tab are visited could shed some light on whether I'm right or not.

Comment: Looks like a nice idea for a userscript :) I would still prefer if it was natively available, but I understand the reluctance to expose it further (even I got a little pissed off after opening it on MSO, can imagine the fuss if it became a prominent feature).